# Datatable laravel cannot find the data of an object

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable

I have a problem that I could not solve, in practice I wanted to get back to my ajax call mixed custom data between data obtained from two models, then I did my queries I did a for cycle and I created a custom array to pass to the ajax call on the view, the problem that gives me an error saying that it doesn't find the data-> folder on the button, sorry but I'm a novice I don't even know if I used a right practice in doing that.

````
```    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $folder=folder::with('person')->where('rpe','AB')->where('des',1)->get();

            foreach($folder as $folder)
            {
                $person=Person::find($folder->person);
                $data[] = [
                    'name' => $person->name,
                    'surname' => $person->surname,
                    'folder' => $folder->p_r,
                ];
            }
            return DataTables::of($data)
                    ->addColumn('action', function($data){

                        $button = '<button type="button" name="handle" id="'.$data->folder.'" class="handle btn btn-primary btn-sm">Handle</button>';
                        return $button;
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action'])
                    ->make(true);
        }
        return view('test');
    }```
This is ajax in the view 
``` $(document).ready(function(){

$('#user_table').DataTable({
 processing: false,
 serverSide: true,
 ajax: {
  url: "{{ route('test.index') }}",
 },
 columns: [
  {
   data: 'name',
   name: 'name'
  },
  {
   data: 'surname',
   name: 'surname'
  },
  {
   data: 'action',
   name: 'action',
   orderable: false
  }]
});});
```
without ``` id = "'. $ data-> p_r.``` works all all fields in the datatable are printed as soon as I put it tells me: *"draw": 1, "recordsTotal": 3, "recordsFiltered": 0, "data": [], "error": "Exception Message: n trying to get property 'folder’ of non-object"}*
````

Comment: Ok i resolve the problem it's not $data->folder but $data['folder']

Answer (score 0):

Try one of below solution-

1. In below line-

   $button = 'folder.'" class="handle btn btn-primary btn-sm">Handle';

There is no property as 'folder' inside variable $data. Debug or show the value of $data.

2. Change below line -

   $button = 'folder.'" class="handle btn btn-primary btn-sm">Handle';

   To

   $button = 'folder ?? NULL).'" class="handle btn btn-primary btn-sm">Handle';

Comment: Then if I don't put the id field in the button equal to $ data-> folder it works, also doing a print of $ date gives me the 3 fields filled, but I need the field folder inside date, how could I solve the perhaps problem is it wrong to transform the collection given by the model Folder which is an array with an array inside a single array with the fields of the two arrays? Perhaps a collection should be passed? If so how do I do it?